# php include is not working cordova android app

Tags: php, html, cordova

I have a index.php which is split into multiple modules like header.php, footer.php and when i use  require method available in php i.e (require(header.php), require(footer.php)) it works fine in browsers and it's is not working when i converted it into android apk using cordova 3.0.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They aren't related. You can't have server side code running on client.